# How can I share a website to a client in which I have built locally using MAMP but is not hosted yet?

Tags: web, localhost, mamp

How can I show a website to a client in which I have built locally using MAMP but is not hosted yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Bring your Mac to the client, and show them the website.

Comment: They are 700 miles away.

Answer (score 0):

Send them the html, php, javascript etc. files via email. Tell them to put the files in one directory and to run the main html file.

Answer (score 0):

1. in your internet router, make a port forwarder, lets say 1333
2. make this port forward to your computer local ip address/localhost, ex 192.168.0.9/localhost
3. give your client the ip address and the port, ex 43.13.19.33:1333